# Is there a simple way to customize how arrays are formatted by JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, stringify

I often want to "pretty print" (include extra white-space to make it easier for humans to interpret) JavaScript objects, and `JSON.stringify(myObject, null, "  ")` usually suffices for this. However, in many cases, there are arrays of numbers that I really don't want split onto new lines.

**Is there a simple/elegant way of accomplishing this with the [native `JSON.stringify` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?**

I tried using a "replacer" function but this seems to only facilitate alteration (e.g. modify data), filtering (e.g. omit data), and side-effects (e.g. log data) -- see also [How Do I Use The Replacer Function With JSON Stringify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873496/how-do-i-use-the-replacer-function-with-json-stringify).

**Alternatively, is there an established module/library/utility for doing this already or should I write my own?**

There appear to be [many search results on npm.org for "stringify"](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=stringify), but the ones I saw seem to just be variations that either run more efficiently on a particular problem domain or avoid problems related to circular/cyclic data structures.

```js
const obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  oneLine: [1,2,3],
  multipleLines: [{
    name: "X",
    alsoOneLine: [4,5,6]
  }, {
    name: "Y"
  }]
};

document.write(`
  <pre>
    // This isn't the output I want. 
    // The arrays containing only numbers should have their elements
    // all printed on the same line.
    ${JSON.stringify(obj, null, "  ")}
  </pre>
`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to search the stringified version for arrays of numbers, and replace the whitespaces in all those those arrays-of-numbers with the empty string. By anchoring the beginning of the pattern to the beginning of a line with `^`, you can ensure that the matched key-value pair (or plain value, in the case the array of numbers is contained in another array) is an *array*, and not something else, like a string that contains something that looks like a JSON-array-of-numbers:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  oneLine: [1, 2, 3],
  multipleLines: [{
    name: "X",
    alsoOneLine: [4, 5, 6],
    inner: [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6]
    ]
  }, {
    name: "Y"
  }]
};

const stringified = JSON.stringify(obj, null, "  ");
const numArraysOnOneLine = stringified.replace(
  /^( *)("[^"]+": )?(\[(?:\s+\d+,)*\s+\d+\s+\])/gm,
  (_, leadingWhitespace, possibleKeyStr='', arrStr) => (
    leadingWhitespace + possibleKeyStr + arrStr.replace(/\s+/g, ''
  ))
);
document.write(`<pre>${numArraysOnOneLine}</pre>`);
```

https://regex101.com/r/XfuqoT/1

The pattern

```
^( *)("[^"]+": )?(\[(?:\s+\d+,)*\s+\d+\s+\])
```

means:

- `^` - Match the start of a line
- `( *)` First capturing group: capture the leading whitespace
- `("[^"]+": )?` Second group, optional: match the double-quoted key, if the array is contained in an object
- `\[` - Beginning of the third group. Match a literal `[`
- `(?:\s+\d+,)*` - Repeat a group of whitespace characters followed by digits zero or more times
- `\s+\d+\s+` - Match the final item in the array (has no trailing comma): whitespace, followed by a digit, followed by more whitespace
- `\]` - followed by the terminating `]` (end of the third group)

If the numbers may contain decimals as well, then replace `\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to allow for optional decimal digits.

If the object properties may contain double-quotes as well (escaped by backslash when stringified), then replace `[^"]+` with `(?:[^"]|\\")+` https://regex101.com/r/XfuqoT/2

Comment: It may potentially break data: `str: "[ 4, 5,    6 ]",`

Comment: Doing post-processing on the result of `JSON.stringify` is an interesting idea. I'm a little leery of counting on the correctness of a RegEx here though as there are potentially many "gotchas". I would prefer a more programmatic approach that's easier to verify.

Comment: Perhaps this could be combined with a "replacer" function that identifies properties to be processed by the post-processing RegEx, e.g. if an array of all numbers is found then it can be modified as a string with the desired result but prefixed with a special sequence like `__CONVERT_THIS_STRING_TO_AN_ARRAY__` which the RegEx could detect and remove along with the quotes, making it an array again.

Comment: @iX3 I did initially think about something like that, but it seemed like an ugly hack. But the `toJSON` method seems to produce the output you're looking for already (correctly, without edge cases, assuming ES6), right?

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't notice the `toJSON` solution (read before your edit). That does appear to do what I want. I don't generally like modifying native prototypes, but this can be easily undone afterward as needed. I'm marking this as the accepted answer for that.

Comment: Oops, sorry, no, it does not work. The `toJSON` solution you provided causes the array to become a quoted string. [`toJSON` behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior): "...instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized."

Comment: @iX3 Oh, I see, you're completely right. While it could be "fixed" by going through the stringified version later and replacing lines containing strings that look like arrays of numbers, that would give incorrect results for inputs which *actually contain* values which are strings which look like arrays of numbers. I think the regular expression solution will work, mainly just need to anchor it to the beginning of a line to ensure it matches true arrays `[` only.